# Download a file from ftp and save in the same folder

Tags: php, ftp

I need to download a file from a remote ftp every 15 min and save in the same folder I run the script. Also this must be a secure script that cannot be read from the web. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a place for asking help with writing code, not having other people do it for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**1) Download.php**

```
<?php

// define some variables
$local_file = 'local.zip';
$server_file = 'server.zip';

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);

?>
```

**2) Set up a Chronjob**

Assuming your using a debian-based Linux distro you have to the following:

`sudo crontab -e`

Insert a new line like this:

`0/15 * * * php -f '/path/to/your/Download.php'`

Comment: Bene, thank you very much for your generous reply, much appreciated it. When other people wanted to close my question, without blinking you helped. I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Bene, it is not working for me, I believe I'm not replacing the correct fields. Please see below what I have done:

<?php

// define some variables
$local_file = 'sku.csv';
$server_file = '/folder/folder1/sku.csv';

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($remoteserver.com);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $my_user_id, $my_pass);

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";

Comment: Better open a new question with the given code and the corresponding error message. Further make sure you filled up the variables with correct values.

Comment: Bene, I'm unable to create a new question. I needed help filling the correct fields.